# Tensorflow, getting NoneType instead of keras.callbacks.History which is expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback, mnist

I'm new to tensorflow, and I kinda struggle with this assignment that shows this error when graded

**Expected:
<class 'keras.callbacks.History'>,
but got:
<class 'NoneType'>.**

The code snippets go as follows.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
```

```
current_dir = os.getcwd()

# Append data/mnist.npz to the previous path to get the full path
data_path = os.path.join(current_dir, "data/mnist.npz")

# Discard test set
(x_train, y_train), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(path=data_path)
        
# Normalize pixel values
x_train = x_train / 255.0
```

```
data_shape = x_train.shape

print(f"There are {data_shape[0]} examples with shape ({data_shape[1]}, {data_shape[2]})")
```

```
class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if(logs.get('accuracy')>0.99):
            print("\nReached 99% accuracy so cancelling training!")
            self.model.stop_training = True

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
```

```
def train_mnist(x_train, y_train):


    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

    (x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

    x_train = x_train / 255
    x_test = x_test / 255

    
    callbacks = myCallback()
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    history=model.fit(
        x_train,
        y_train,
        epochs=10,
        callbacks=[myCallback()]
    )
    return history
```

By default Keras' model. fit() returns a History callback object. Isn't this true? Where do I go wrong?

```
train_mnist(x_train,y_train)
```

Comment: You should clarify this part: " assignment that shows this error when graded", when graded how? with which code?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy the details of the grader code haven't been given. It just tells this error message : (

Comment: Yes well it is hard to debug something without a clear source, did you validate what model.fit is returning?

Comment: Hi @VikneyshRajGGA, I got the same error, assigning `train_mnist(x_train,y_train)` to a variable like `hist=train_mnist(x_train,y_train)` solved the error in my case. Thank you!